# ошибка в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

При создании проекта в Андроид Студио выбивает ошибку
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471311/android-studio-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Уже обсуждался этот вопрос на данном ресурсе. Такое происходит когда системе не хватает ресурсов для запуска демона. Попробуйте проверить характеристики вашей системы с системными требованиями Android Studio на официальном [сайте](http://www.newit.info/android-studio-ot-google-integrirovannaya-sreda-razrabotki-ide/).

Comment: вроде по характеристикам проходит. Может проблема не в этом?

Comment: @antonin14d а вы вот это читали? http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html ?

Comment: @antonin14d там написано следующее:                                           On Windows, this command will enable the Daemon for the current user:
(if not exist "%HOMEPATH%/.gradle" mkdir "%HOMEPATH%/.gradle") && (echo foo >> "%HOMEPATH%/.gradle/gradle.properties")

Comment: @antonin14d  Тоже полезно прочитать этот раздел. 18.2.7. What can go wrong with Daemon?

Comment: плохо английский знаю, это значит что нет .gradle файла?

Comment: кто нибудь скажет, что делать